# ¿Cómo almacenar una lista a una array con todos los datos juntos?

Tags: java, java-swing, selenium, java-8, java-ee

estoy intentando almacenar una lista a una array.
Lo que he estado haciendo, es crear un String y almacenar en una array. Luego hago un bucle para recorrer toda la array y solo seleccionando el primero. Convierto en String el array para luego almacenar en una lista. Esta lista contiene los datos pero no está mostrando todo juntos. Os paso el código:

```
       // list
        ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<>();
        // creamos un String sobre el scenario que queremos seleccionar
        String name = scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString();
        // se lo pasamos a una array
        String[] listSc = name.split(",");
        String finish = "";
        // sacamos el primero de la array
        for (int i=listSc.length-1; i<listSc.length;i++){
             finish =listSc[0].replace("[","").replace("]","");
            System.out.println("for_array "+finish);
            // añadimos a la lista el ultimo que queremos seleccionar
            arrayString.add(finish);

        }
        // cremos una array pasando los parametros del array
        String[] listSc2 = arrayString.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (int b = 0; b <listSc2.length;b++){
            //sacamos el listado, debería sacarnos: A,B pero solo saca de forma individual
            System.out.println("total "+listSc2[b]);
        }
```

Comment: hm... por lo que veo te estas complicando bastante la vida, puedes mostrar bien el contenido de "name" y de listSc. Respecto a porque no muestra todos juntos, diría que tu listSc[0] debería ser listSc[i] pero bueno, creo que podemos optimizar este código.

Comment: Hola mgarciaQA, podrías mostrarnos un ejemplo de la cadena recibida y la esperada?.

Comment: Mientras espero, te voy comentando que la sentencia del primer **for** contiene un pequeño error: **int i = listSc.length-1;** debería ser **int i = 0;**

Comment: Hola Buenas @Marce, si el for, estaba indicando el ultimo de la lista pero ya lo he quitado, no me había dado cuenta. Sobre la cadena que me llega es esta: el String finish, me llega solo un tag por cada ejecución "@TID106007REV0.15.0" solo quiero almacenarlo para que me muestre en array final "@TID106007REV0.15.0,  @TID150045REV0.7.0"

Comment: Buenas @Grismak , si he modificado 0 por el i. Pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: No estoy entendiendo, tu código crea un array partiendo de una cadena segmentada por "," (con el split), se supone que recibes una cadena que contiene ",", por otro lado usas replace( "[", "" ), por lo que se supone que tu cadena contiene "[", es así?

Answer (score 1):

suponiendo que la cadena recibida es:

```
String name = "[pepe],[antonio],[carla],[tito]";
```

hacemos unas ligeras correcciones a tu código.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<>();          
String listSc[] = name.split( "," );
String finish = "";
for (int i = 0; i < listSc.length; i++ ) {
    finish = listSc[ i ].replace( "[","" ).replace( "]","" );
    System.out.println( "for_array " + finish );
    arrayString.add( finish );
}
       
String[] listSc2 =  new String[ 2 ];
String salida = "";
for ( int b = 0; b < arrayString.size(); b++ ) {
    salida += arrayString.get( b ) + ", ";
}
salida = salida.substring( 0, salida.length() - 2 );
System.out.println( salida );
```

}

La primer corrección, como te anticipe en los comentarios, está en la condición del primer **for**, esta pasa a ser **int i = 0;**.
La segunda, esta en la linea siguiente en las que pusiste:

```
*finish = listSc[ 0 ].replace( "[", "" ).replace( "]", "" );*
```

cuando deberías poner:

```
*finish = listSc[ i ].replace( "[", "" ).replace( "]", "" );*
```

Comment: El String name, con tiene [a,b,c,d]. Añado el split para poder seleccionar solo el a

Comment: con el split añades **[a**, pero no hay problema después la linea del replace quita los **[**, lo mismo pasa con **d]**. prueba y dime si te funciona

Comment: aunque sería más óptimo, realizar el **replace** antes del for.

Comment: pregunta, la salida debería ser **a,b** y **c,d**?

Comment: No, debería ser a,b, . . . z. Almacenar todos los datos posibles

Comment: en una sola linea?

Comment: Correcto, para luego llamar al jenkins, pero ya lo tengo. No había creado static fuera del metodo, entonces lo que me estaba ocurriendo es reemplazar el ultimo por el primero. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora paso el código modificado

Comment: Un placer maestro.

Answer (score 1):

Código completo: Ahora aparece de forma correcto, cuando termina la ejecución. Solo muestra todos los datos seleccionado [a,b,..,c]
Gracias a tod@s por ayudarme. @Marce Puente.

```
public static  ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<>();
  public void afterRebuild(Scenario scenario){
        if (scenario.isFailed()){
            // creamos un String sobre el scenario que queremos seleccionar
            String name = scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString().replace("[","").replace("]","");
            // se lo pasamos a una array
            String[] listSc = name.split(",");
            String finish = "";
            // sacamos el primero de la array
            for (int i=0; i< 1;i++){
                 finish =listSc[i];
                // añadimos a la lista el ultimo que queremos seleccionar
                arrayString.add(finish);
            }

            // indicamos la array.toString para que muestre los datos seleccionado
            System.out.println("resultado final "+arrayString.toString());


        }
    }
```